# Exclude a certain div in jQuery global validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so we have around 30 input boxes in our page, and instead of writing a no data line for each one, we have a simple statement:

```
if( $(div).find('input:text[value=""]').length > 0 ||
    $('#checkbox1Wrap').find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length > 0 ||
    $('#checkbox2Wrap').find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length > 0 ||
    $(div).find('select option:first-child:selected').length > 0 ||
    $(div).find('textarea').val() == ""
){
    $(div).prepend('<p class="field_help"> Please complete all fields before moving to next step</p>');
    return false;
}
```

This checks all input fields to check if their length is more than 0, but we want to exclude certain fields from being checked.

For example:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" name="ext" id="ext">
```

We don't want the above input field to be checked.

How can we make it so the if statement skips certain defined IDs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.not()` method:

```
$(div).find('input:text[value=""]').not('#id1, #id2')
```

Docs here: http://api.jquery.com/not/

I should note that one standard way of doing this is a bit simpler, however, if you don't mind mixing the business logic of the form with your HTML markup:

1. In HTML, add a `required` CSS class to all required elements.
2. In jQuery, specify that class in your selector:

   ```
   `$(div).find('input.required:text[value=""]')`
   ```

Now only required elements are validated. There are a couple of advantages to this approach:

- You can easily use CSS to visually indicate required fields
- The selectors are simpler
- If you decide you need more complex validation, you're already set up to use [jquery-validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

You could do the same thing in the opposite direction using an `optional` class too, but I think `required` is a bit better semantically.

Comment: this sounds great, is there an opposite to .not()? So we can enforce it if it IS? If that makes any sense?

Comment: Not sure I follow. If you use `.not()`, the elements you're excluding aren't in the set, so you'd have to `.add()` specific ones back in afterwards: `.not('.general').add('#specific')` catches the `specific` element even if it has the `general` class. Is that what you mean? Otherwise, all the elements in your set are enforced, right?

Comment: @Latox - see edit - I was thinking about this, and I think the method I describe above is preferable.